# How to print initial letter of committer in git log?

Tags: regex, git, logging, configuration, pretty-print

I have prepared an alias to get a short log report in git

```
# excerpt from ~/.gitconfig
[alias]
    lg = log --all --oneline --graph --decorate --pretty='%C(auto)%h %Cgreen%ai %C(reset)%C(auto)%s %d'
```

`git lg` generates one nice line per commit, but without information on the user:

```
* 623beff 2016-11-14 14:18:36 +0100 extended plotstyle option and automatic colors
```

or as screenshot:

[image: example screenshot]

**But** I want to see the **initial letters of the committer real name** (the full name is sometimes too long) in each line:

```
* 623beff 2016-11-14 14:18:36 +0100 (J.S.) extended plotstyle option and automatic colors
```

How can I get this result?

Answer (score 1):

there is a way to do this to get the first letter of the first name, using `%<(3,trunc)%cN`:

```
git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate --pretty='%C(auto)%h %Cgreen%ai %C(reset)%C(auto)(%<(3,trunc)%cN) %s %d'
```

output:

```
* 8759307 2009-01-15 16:11:48 +0000 (S..) Remove spurious code trying to tag a branch root before the mark was created.  (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
* 939f999 2008-12-11 13:41:37 +0000 (S..) When just writing output file, do not try to devise lock target with no repository.
```